# Motherboard Failing, Must Move RAID 5 Array To New Computer

Tags: raid

I have a client running a raid 5 array for his data drives on a motherboard with built in raid support. (Not a controller)

He has another computer with a hardware raid controller he can use to rebuild the old array. Is it possible to transfer this old array to the new controller?

I was thinking about making an image of the old array with dd or Acronis, re initializing the drives on the new controller and then cloning back.

Is this a possible solution? He has backups of his data but would prefer to keep the existing structure the way it is.

Comment: Well if you create the image you have nothing to worry about to be honest.

Comment: Image, rebuild with new controller and restore. Saves having to deal with issues between controllers.